# Google Custom Search returning too many pages

Tags: google-custom-search

In our site we have a custom google search. When you do a search all ten paginated pages come back, however the last three or four will be empty and just display "No Results"

[image: no results]

from what I've been reading, this shouldn't happen. If there are no results on the page then it should redirect you to the last page that does have content. Is there an attribute to make sure this happens?

the code looks something like this

```
      (function() {                                                                                    
  var id= '#id#'; // Insert your own Custom Search engine ID here                                     
      var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;   
      gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +                        
              '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + id;                                                  
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);          
  })();
```

and then

```
 <gcse:searchresults-only ></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this? I'm getting the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `resultSetSize` attribute to limit the result set? This should limit to a *maximum* of 10 pages with 10 results per page. If there are fewer results, you shouldn't get 10 records. I believe the default here is `10` in place of `filtered_cse`.

```
<gcse:searchresults-only resultSetSize="filtered_cse"></gcse:searchresults-only>
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm getting back less than ten pages of results, but the pagination is still showing pages 1-10. When you click on one of those links that has no results on the page then you get the "no results" message I posted above.